# MYSQL create table not creating all fields

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have a class that creates all the tables needed for my application. The problem I have is that not all fields are being created. The code executes without any errors. Even with Try Catch it does not jump to the catch block showing that the code is run successfully.

The code does this for the entire create table section of my code where it will skip the last two fields that it's suppose to create.

The code below is the problematic code and like I said before I'm not getting a syntax error or any other error when I debug
There are far more tables that gets created, but with all of them doing the same thing I will only post one of the statements

```c#
string CreateSuppliers = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SUPPLIERS (SupplierName Char(50), SypplierType Char(50), SupplierPaid Float, SupplierOwed Float, DateCaptured Char(50))";
        string CreatePaymentsReceived = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PaymentsReceived (CustomerName Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50), AmountPaid Float, AmountDue Float, PaymentType Char(50), PaymentVat Float, ProofOfPayment Char(255), DateCaptured Char(50), DateOnInvoice Char(50))";
        string CreatePaymentsPaid = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PaymentsMade (CustomerName Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50), AmountPaid Float, AmountDue Float, PaymentType Char(50), PaymentVat Float, ProofOfPayment Char(255), DateCaptured Char(50), DateOnInvoice Char(50))";
        string CreateReturns = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Returns (CustomerName Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50), AmountPaid Float, AmountDue Float, PaymentType Char(50), ProofOFPayment Char(255), DateCaptured Char(50), DateOnInvoice Char(50))";
        string CreateEmployeeSalary = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EmployeeSalary (EmployeeName Char(50), EmployeeNumber Char(50), EmployeeSalaryPaid Float, EmployeeSalayDue Float, PaymentType Char(50), ProofOfPayment Char(255), DateCaptured Char(50), DateOnInvoice Char(50))";
        string CreateDirectorInvestment = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DirectorInvestment (Date Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50), AmountPaid Float, PaymentType Char(50), DateCaptured Char(50))";
        string CreateDirectorWithdraw = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DirectorWithdraw (Date Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50), AmountWithdraw Float, PaymentType Char(50), DateCaptured Char(50))";
        string CreateCustomerAccounts = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CustomerAccounts (CustomerName Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50), AccountTypeDays Float, ContractPapers Char(50))";
        string CreateJournal = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Journal (JournalName Char(50), ReferenceNumber Char(50),PaymentMade Float, PaymentReceived Float, FromAccount Char(50), DateCaptured Char(50), DateOnInvoice Char(50))";
        string CreateExpenses = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Expenses (InvoiceNumber Char(50),Company Char(50), AmountPaid Float, AmountDue Float, PaymentType Char(50), PaymentVat Float, ProofOfPayment Char(50), MonthlyPayment Char(50), DateCaptured Char(50), DateOnOnvoice Char(50))";
        string CreateUserAccounts = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AccountingUsers (UserName Char(50), Password Char(255),AdminLevel Char(50), LastLogin Char(50))";

       

        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new
        MySqlConnection(serverstring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(CreateSuppliers, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase2 = new MySqlCommand(CreatePaymentsReceived, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase3 = new MySqlCommand(CreatePaymentsPaid, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase4 = new MySqlCommand(CreateReturns, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase5 = new MySqlCommand(CreateEmployeeSalary, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase6 = new MySqlCommand(CreateDirectorInvestment, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase7 = new MySqlCommand(CreateDirectorWithdraw, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase8 = new MySqlCommand(CreateCustomerAccounts, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase9 = new MySqlCommand(CreateJournal, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase10 = new MySqlCommand(CreateUserAccounts, conDatabase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase11 = new MySqlCommand(CreateExpenses, conDatabase);

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.firstLaunch == true)
        {
            string HashedPassword;
            HashPassword HP = new HashPassword();
            HP.password = "WonderConnect";
            HP.Hashingthepassword();
            HashedPassword = HP.HashedPassword;
            string cmdText = "INSERT INTO AccountingUsers(UserName, Password, AdminLevel) VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @AdminLevel)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conDatabase);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", "WonderConnect");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", HashedPassword);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdminLevel", "Admin");

            try
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase6.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase7.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase8.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase9.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase10.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase11.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conDatabase.Close();
                Properties.Settings.Default.firstLaunch = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errormsg =ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase6.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase7.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase8.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase9.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase10.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdDatabase11.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conDatabase.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errormsg =ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Is this something wrong with the code or is my MYSQL not working as it should?

Comment: Why do you add an empty string to the query string? (It wouldn't cause an error but it looks funny and may indicate you omitted to much in what you posted?)

Comment: Side note: Think about you SQL data types again. For example you use `char(50)` for what appears to be dates. You shouldn't do that but use a proper date type.

Comment: thank you , Ill change the Data types, but i till need to know why its not creating those fields, like i said there's no errors when compiling or running

Comment: Given that you're using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, are you sure these tables don't already exist?  Also, the last column in `Expenses` is `DateOnOnvoice`, which I'm guessing is a typo for `DateOnInvoice`.

Comment: Thank you for showing the typo, saved me a lot of headache down the road, I even tried dropping all the tables, to recreate to see if that was the problem, and still even creating fresh tables they still don't create the last two fields

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you, for testing, try to create a table with only two columns? What happens if you try it with just one column?

Comment: Taking another look there are further typos: `SypplierType` in the first `CREATE TABLE` statement, and you've also consistently misspelled 'Amount`.  That aside, there is simply no reason why MySQL would create a table and intentionally miss off the last two columns you asked it to create.  So something else must be happening.  Maybe you are running an old version of your code, or your app has other code that creates these tables without the two extra columns.  What happens if you get rid of the `IF NOT EXISTS` from these statements?

Comment: Thank you to everyone that helped here, even showing out my typos. Looks like the issue was not with the code but rather my visual studio server explorer. it was not dropping the tables as it should, and when you refreshed, the old data would be shown again